# Custom Quick Actions on Tasks available in Napili Community?

Tags: community, napili

I created a quick action on Opportunity to create a new task and default some fields. It is working just find in regular Salesforce but the Quick Action button does not show in the Napili Community and I cannot figure out why.

I haven't found documentation that mentions that custom quick actions on Activities are not available in Community... but that's the only explanation I can come up with.

Answer (score 0):

Try "force:lightningQuickAction" interface

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction" access="global">
```